# Php, Spl, SimpleXMLIterator

Tags: php, xml, spl

I am trying to understand some guide part, I kind of really lost the logic at  the following explanation:

**First The Code**:[Link](http://codepad.org/fYNMzH1W)

**Now the guide**:

> A problem arises in XML when two documents may have similar names. If
>   we had the xml document of animals, and another of animal owners, a
>   conflict may arise in the name node. Each of the animals, and owners
>   would have a name node and a method is required to distinguish between
>   them. The SimpleXMLIterator provides several methods for the
>   management of namespaces. These include as listed in the top of the
>   this chapter. The script below shows a small change to the xml string
>   that has been used and demonstrates the use of namespaces and how to
>   utilize them within the SimpleXMLIterator.

**This was the part coming before the code is given, Now this is the part given after the code**:

> In the script above we have declared a namespace in our root as
>    Also not the
>   addtion to the XML of a second name node. This is prefixed by the
>   spec: prefix to identify the namespace and not confuse it with the
>   regular animal names. The use of the
>   SimpleXMLIterator::registerXPathNamespace() method ensures the
>   document namespace prefixing is sane. To get the namespaces the
>   SimpleXMLIterator::getDocNamespaces() method is used to get the names
>   of all namespaces declared within the document. The
>   SimpleXMLIterator::getNamespaces() method could also have been used.
>   The SimpleXMLIterator::getDocNamespaces() method only gets those
>   namespaces that are actually declared within the document itself.

**The problem**:

The problem is that i dont think i understand right the author, If some one please can explain this code with another words, I will name weak spots at the code my logic failed to understand:

- The Tag (spec:name) // **At the XML code.**
- $sxi-> registerXPathNamespace('spec', 'http://www.exampe.org/species-title'); // **This method and the 2 parameters.**
- $result = $sxi->xpath('//spec:name'); // **This method with the parameter.**
- $sxi->getDocNamespaces('animal') // **At the foreach loop.**

If can someone please focus on those parts i mentioned and try another words, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: All of your questions have the same title and seem to ask the same question over and over again.

Comment: This question is talking again about SimpleXMLIterator but its not the same as before at the start i was talking about SimpleXMLIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator next it was SimpleXMLIterator output witch skip elements, now its about "NameSpace".